# Random string in cucumber scenarios

Tags: cucumber, bdd, gherkin

I am testing a GUI using cucumber. I need to test CRUD operations of the GUI.

When I write a scenario to create a new entity in GUI, I am unable to run multiple times, since the second time scenario fails because the ID I specified for the entity already exists (created in the first run) in the system the second time I run the test.

The system I am testing doesn't allow deleting entities. System needs to be started in a special mode to delete entities, so deleting the entity created after the test is not an option.

It would be great if I could use a random number for the entity id. For an example:

```
when user creates a new Branch with following values:
|Branch ID|<random_string_1>|
|Address|1, abc, def.|
|Telephone|01111111111|
And user searches for a branch by "Branch ID" = "<random_string_1>"
Then branch details should be as following
|Branch ID|<random_string_1>|
|Address|1, abc, def.|
|Telephone|01111111111|
```

Is there an option in cucumber to do something like this? Or, is there any other way I can achieve this?

Comment: Why not create the id using some randomizer function of the programming language? It seems like the id is only used in this scenario only. Then u will have no need to mention the id details in the feature file.

Comment: @Grasshopper The name of the ID field is different for each entity type. The step def to create an entity with given details is generic and it works for any entity type, so I would have to write special logic which depends on the entity type. That's why I didn't like to do it that way. Also, the used random string needs to be referred in later steps. For an example, the second step of above example uses the same random string.

Comment: Then keep the id field in the scenario and mention a specific key for each entity type (if this adds any value) or just any string. Replace or add on the generated random string inside the programming language. Once you have the id string in the stepdef you can store it and use it pretty easily for further steps or scenarios.

Comment: @Grasshopper I was thinking about a similar approach: In each step definition implementation, pass the arguments to a method `preProcessArguments()`. In this method, check for strings matching a special key pattern (eg: <random_sting_1>), and replace them with random strings (generate new one and store if key is not already found, or use the stored value for the key if already found). Wanted to check whether there is a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, I've added `RandomStringTransformer` class to test suite:

```java
    public class RandomStringTransformer extends Transformer<String> {
        private static final Map<String, String> RANDOM_STRINGS = new HashMap<>();   //Key -> random string
        public static final RandomStringTransformer INSTANCE = new RandomStringTransformer();

        @Override
        public String transform(String input) {
            return transformString(input);
        }

        public DataTable transform(DataTable dataTable) {
            dataTable.getGherkinRows().forEach(dataTableRow -> dataTableRow.getCells().replaceAll(this::transformString));
            return dataTable;
        }

        private String transformString(String input) {
            final String[] inputCopy = {input};
            Map<String, String> replacements = new HashMap<>();
            Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(<random_string_[^>]*>)").matcher(input);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                String group = matcher.group(0);
                replacements.put(group, RANDOM_STRINGS.computeIfAbsent(group, key -> Utilities.getNextUniqueString()));
            }
            replacements.forEach((key, value) -> inputCopy[0] = inputCopy[0].replace(key, value));
            return inputCopy[0];
        }
    }
```

And used the transformer in step definition:

```java
    @When("^user creates a branch of name "([^"]*)" with following values$")
    public void branchIsCreatedWithDetails(@Transform(RandomStringTransformer.class) String branchName, DataTable fieldValues) {
        fieldValues = RandomStringTransformer.INSTANCE.transform(fieldValues);
        //Now, fieldValues table values and branchName are replaced with random values if they were in format <random_string_SOMETHING>
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `@Transform` annotation is not supported in Cucumber 3 anymore.
You have to transform data manually in the method body.

```java
@When("^user creates a branch of name "([^"]*)" with following values$")
public void branchIsCreatedWithDetails(String branchName, DataTable fieldValues) {
    fieldValues = RandomStringTransformer.INSTANCE.transform(fieldValues);
    //Now, fieldValues table values and branchName are replaced with random values if they were in format <random_string_SOMETHING>
}
```

Read this for more information to migrate: http://grasshopper.tech/98/